# Solution of $\frac{dy}{dx}+x(x+y)=x^3(x+y)^3 -1$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> The solution of differential equation $$\frac{dy}{dx}+x(x+y)=x^3(x+y)^3-1$$

what i try:

put $x+y=v,$ Then $\displaystyle 1+\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{dv}{dx}\Rightarrow \frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{dv}{dx}-1$

did not know how i eliminate $x$ in original equation

How do i solve it after that please help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $(x+y)=v$, then $\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{dv}{dx}-1$, then the ODE becomes
$$\frac{dv}{dx}+xv=x^3v^3 \implies v^{-3}\frac{dv}{dx}+xv^{-2}=x^3$$ This Benoulli Eq., next takr $v^{-2}=u$, then
$$\frac{du}{dx}-2xu=-2x^3$$ This is lineaqr Eq. whose Integrating factor is $I=e^{-x^2}$, the its solution is
$$u=e^{x^2}\int -2x^3 e^{-x^2} dx +C e^{x^2} \implies u=(1+x^2)+C e^{x^2}
\implies (x+y)^{-2}=(1+x^2)+Ce^{x^2}$$

Answer (score 1):

It's Bernouilli's equation, here is my approach:
$$\frac{dy}{dx}+x(x+y)=x^3(x+y)^3 -1$$
$$(x+y)'+x(x+y)=x^3(x+y)^3 $$

$$((x+y)e^{x^2/2})'=x^3e^{x^2/2}(x+y)^3 $$
$$\frac {((x+y)e^{x^2/2})'}{((x+y)e^{x^2/2})^3}=x^3e^{-x^2} $$
$$-\frac 12  \frac {1}{(x+y)^2e^{x^2}}= \int x^3e^{-x^2}dx $$
$$-\frac {1}{(x+y)^2e^{x^2}}=  -x^2e^{-x^2}-e^{-x^2}  +C $$
$$\boxed{\frac {1}{(x+y)^2}=  (x^2+1)+Ce^{x^2} } $$